# Concatenating in Razor

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying a simple concatenation in razor.
I get all kinds of squiqly lines when I add this in my model RAZOR:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ck1-@track.TrackID" 
 onclick="$('#ck2-@(track.TrackID)').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'))" />
```

However it outputs perfectly OUTPUT:

```
<input type="checkbox"
       id="ck1-500004524"
       onclick="$('#ck2-500004524').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'))">
```

I am trying to get the exact html as in the output, but without all of the squigly.
I understand this is most likely covered in other posts, but I am still trying to get the grasp on the way Razor concatenates strings, it seems to be different each time I need it.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: is it important for you to be able to use the razor to create the event handler any way possible or does the solution have to be injected into html markup

Comment: It's not important, I just want to get rid of the squiqly's, they appear in my error list...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, Razor isn't friendly to injecting variables into html attributes. Part of the reason is that linking event handlers in Mark-up is an outdated practice.

best practice is the "Unobtrusive way"

```
$(function () {

   $('#').click(function () 
 { $('#ck2-@(track.TrackID)').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked')) })


})
```

Comment: I would love to learn this style of writing code, can you please help?  This is in a table, each row has 2 checkboxes, one as the first column the other is the last. The task is to check/uncheck both checkboxes when one is checked.

Comment: I wrote the function like this: `function dupCheckBox(element) {
        var tableRow = $(element).parents('tr');
        
                      $(tableRow).children('td').children('input:checkbox').each(function () {
            this.checked = $(element).is(':checked');
        });
    }` and the razor code like this: `<input type="checkbox" id="ck1-@(track.TrackId)" onclick="dupCheckBox(this);"/>`. I am not sure if this is unobtrusive...

Comment: whenever you use onclick, it is obtrusive. the idea is to separate your jscript from html. the event handler i added above does similar but is not embedded in html

Comment: I figured it out, thanks for pointing out the "Unobtrusive way".

Comment: Thanks, please take a look at the answer I provided below, I would love any feedback...

Answer (score 0):

Having @code inside of html/javascript strings e.g "@code" or '@code' will almost always give you squiggly lines.

Answer (score 0):

On lines where I am mixing HTML markup & Razor syntax, I preface the line with a `@:` which I've found resolves a lot of issues.

Also, check out http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/16/asp-net-mvc-3-implicit-and-explicit-code-nuggets-with-razor.aspx

This snippet is good advice:

> When necessary, you can also explicitly scope code expressions using a
>   @(expression) syntax to provide greater clarity around your intent, as
>   well as to disambiguate code statements from static markup.

Comment: Thank you da7rutrak. So I re-wrote it like this, I am not happy with having to write out code like this. Any one have a better way of writing this? `@Html.Raw("<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"ck2-" + track.TrackID + "\" onclick=\"$('#ck1-" + track.TrackID + "').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'))\" />")`

Comment: You are welcome. I would definitely look into what @Dave A said above!

Comment: Sorry for not giving you the answer, I think this way is the wrong way of doing this. Please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for everyone that helped, one of the answers suggested that the 'unobrusive way' would be better than hardcoding javascript into the elements. Here is what I came up with:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="ckSelectCol" />

$(function () {
    $('.ckSelectCol').each(function () {
        $(this).change(function () {
            dupCheckBox(this);
        });
    });
});
```

What this is doing is finding all checkboxes that have a class ckSelectCol and adding a change eventhandler, the change event handler is the function that I wish to be called on change.

This can be done a multitude of ways, I chose this way as it decouples the javascript from the page, can easily be reused and makes the page lighter.

If anyone has any suggestions, please respond.

Once again, I appreciate all of the input that I received on this post.

-Edward

Comment: Ic see, you hitched to the change event. that's clever.